# Regex - find specific number in string

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm struggling with regular expression whole day and couldn't find a solution.
I'm trying to find some specific number in strings that contains numbers, semicolons, colons and whitespaces.

For our purpose let's say I'm looking for number **1234**

Here are few examples which should match (**Every line is a different string**):

```
1234
;1234;
1234 : 5678
;1234,3321
```

And example that shouldn't match (because it's different number):

```
;12345;
0123456
```

My current attempt:

```
[^(0-9*)]1234[^(0-9*)]
```

Here is a permalink to Regex Tester with my problem:
[Regex Tester fiddle](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5B%5E%280-9%2a%29%5D1234%5B%5E%280-9%2a%29%5D&input=1234;12343%20-%20Should%20match%20a%20string%20that%20begins%20with%20nothing%20and%20ends%20with%20semicolon%20and%20other%20numbers%0A;31234;%20-%20It%20contains%20number%20that%20we%20look%20for,%20but%20it%27s%20a%20different%20number%20so%20it%20shouldn%27t%20match%0A1234%20-%20Definitely%20should%20match%0A;1234;%20-%20Should%20match)

Comment: In which language or tool are you going to use the pattern eventually? Also, this is not how character classes word, you are looking for negative [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: `[^(0-9*)]` means not a digit (`0-9`), parentheses (`(` or `)`) or a star `*`. You may want to use simply `[^0-9]` (not a digit).

Comment: I'm going to use it in MySQL using REGEX in WHERE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try this: `([^0-9]|^)1234([^0-9]|$)` In this case you don't need the lookaround features.

You can use this to understand regexp better. It has a nice gui to visualize the pattern. [Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/)

Comment: Note that this will fail to match the number at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: The '1234' will be taken as repeat count for the set

Comment: In some implementations it will. not all use {n} for repeat count

Comment: @Jay: You have an example of one that doesn't?  Every regex implementation i've ever seen that allows repeat counts, uses either `{}` or `\{\}` to delimit them.

Comment: @Jay the one used by the OP's regex tester (ECMAScript) doesn't. Neither do most popular (Perl-based or POSIX-based ones). I'd be very interested in a counterexample though.

Comment: Sorry, can't locate it any longer. If I can't locate it it's probably been deprecated out of existence.

Comment: Works like a charm, it works in my MySQL query ! :)) I've tried it before with ^ as beginning and $ as end but in some other way and it didn't work. Thank You Very much !

Answer (score 3):

If your flavor supports [**lookahead and lookbehind**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), go with this:

```
(?<!\d)1234(?!\d)
```

Lookaround tests for occurences of characters without matching them. Negative lookaround only accepts when there is no occurence.

If it supports [**word boundaries**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
\b1234\b
```

Word boundaries include eg. whitespace and punctuation.

Otherwise check for non-digit characters and add string start and end:

```
(^|\D)1234($|\D)
```

---

If your engine does not even support `\d` and `\D`, replace them by `[0-9]` respective `[^0-9]`.

Comment: `^` and `$` in a character class are just literal characters. You need to use the anchors outside of it with an alternation like `(?:^|\D)...(?:\D|$)`

Comment: Aye, was too fast -- edited my post, but omitted the non-matching groups as this was no requirement, but makes the query more complicated.

Comment: Sure, that's fine. I just think, even though it clutters up the pattern, it's one of the most important regex habits to get into. Because someone who *does* know that normal parentheses do capture might otherwise be confused what we are capturing for - so I always try to be explicit and avoid any unnecessary overhead at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
.*[^0-9]*[1][2][3][4][^0-9]*.*
```

How it works:

```
.*             anything
[^0-9]*        an optional character that is not a number
[1][2][3][4]   "1234" done this way because it will be taken as a repeat count unless escaped
[^0-9]*        an optional character that is not a number
.*             anything
```

There might be an issue with strings that start or end with "1234" and have no other characters. The match for anything on the front and back may not be needed depending on the implementation of regex.

Comment: Since the `[^0-9]` are optional, the `.*` can match everything except the `1234` (including adjacent numbers). Also there's no need to put the numbers in classes.

Comment: They will be taken as a repeat count unless escaped

Comment: No they won't. that's `{1234}`

Comment: No, they won't.  Repeat counts are in `{}`.